# How to get control over Bootstrap 3 fluid width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get better control over how Bootstrap 3 is scaling my col width.

Lets say for example that i create two columns using the following code:

```
   <div class="xs-col-6"></div>
   <div class="xs-col-6"></div>
```

When I re-size the window I want the the first column to take up 80% of the space and the right one to use 20% of the space. How can i do this?

This is what I tried:

```
    <div class="xs-col-6" style="width:80%;"></div>
    <div class="xs-col-6" style="width:20%;"></div>
```

Comment: Can use $(window).resize(function(){}); to resize the width of class using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bootstrap you can use column, they are 12, so you can have this (9+3 = 12):

```
<div class="col-xs-9"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
```

also, you can have different behavior  depending on the device size with `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*` and `col-lg-*`.
Like this :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-6"></div>
```

And if you want overwrite bootstrap css, you can, but maybe you need to add `!important` to your css property

Comment: Now i finally understand how to use col. Thanks alot!